# problem with passing parameter to the function assigned with the default exit window button in Tkinter, using "root.protocol"

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda, command, protocols

I would love some help, thanks!

I am trying to use *lambdas* to assign functionality to window events. It already worked for assigning the "enter" button to a function.

But, for some reason, it doesn't work for the default exit button on the window.
As you can see in the `create_entry_window` function, I used a *lambda* twice, and it worked only for the "Return".

The problem occurs with this line:

```
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", (lambda event: exit_entry(root)))
```

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, BOTTOM, Entry, Text, END

def clear_and_get_entry(root, entry):
    """

    """
    global entered_text
    entry_text = entry.get()
    entry.delete(0, END)
    entry.insert(0, "")
    entered_text = entry_text
    root.destroy()


def exit_entry(root):
    """

    """
    global entered_text
    entered_text = False
    print "here at exit"
    root.destroy()


def create_entry_window(text):
    """

    """
    root = Tk()
    root.title("One picture is worth a thousand sounds!")
    root.geometry("500x200")
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    bottom_frame = Frame(root)
    bottom_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    entry = Entry(root)
    entry.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    description_text = Text(root, height=50, width=100)
    description_text.insert(END, text)
    description_text.tag_configure("center", justify='center')
    description_text.tag_add("center", "1.0", "end")
    description_text.pack()
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", (lambda event: exit_entry(root)))
    entry.bind("<Return>", (lambda event: clear_and_get_entry(root, entry)))
    return root 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = create_entry_window("Some text")
    root.mainloop()
```

When trying to exit the window, I get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Heights\PortableApps\PortablePython2.7.6.1\App\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick-fix to your problem is quite easy:

Change the line reading `root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", (lambda event: exit_entry(root)))`  into

```
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: exit_entry(root))
```

The root.protocol does not provide an argument when triggered. But your *lambda* expects one. Removing the argument `event` fixes the problem for me.

Please note that there are some other issues with your code.

You are still using Python 2. Unless there are very compelling reasons to do so, I suggest you move forward to Python 3. I had not problems running your code with Python 3. All I needed to do was to add brackets to the `print` statement:
`print "here at exit"` -> `print("here at exit")`

Secondly: You are using `global` in order for your functions to communicate with each other. This is considered bad-practice. It leads to confusing code that is very hard to debug. I suggest that you have a closer look at some tkinter examples and how they are using an object oriented approach to deal with this issue. A possible starting point could be [Introduction_to_GUI_Programming](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Introduction_to_GUI_Programming.html). The [Calculator](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Introduction_to_GUI_Programming.html#putting-it-all-together) class looks like a good starting-point to me.